# The Shortcut in a PySide2 MenuItem prevents window from showing

Tags: python, qml, qtquick2, shortcut, pyside2

I'm trying to create a very simple ApplicationWindow using PySide2 (Qt for Windows) and QML.

main.py

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    url = QUrl("mainWindow.qml")
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(url)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

qml file

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    title: "MainWindow"
    width: 640
    height: 480

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        id: menuBar

        Menu {
            id: editMenu
            title: "&Edit"

            MenuItem {
                id: copyItem
                text: "Copy"
                // This doesn't work:
                // shortcut: "Ctrl+C"
                // This doesn't work either:
                // shortcut: StandardKey.Copy
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As shown, the code runs and displays an ApplicationWindow with a MenuBar and the Menu. But if I outcomment either of the two shortcut variants the window isn't shown at all. I don't understand, why. My example follows the [Qt documentation on MenuItems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menuitem.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QML there are 2 types of items: `Qt Quick Controls 1` and `Qt Quick Controls 2`. Both groups have items with the same name but they differ in their properties, in your case `MenuItem` of `Qt Quick Controls 2` does not have a shortcut property but instead `Qt Quick Controls 1` if it has it so the solution is to change the import:

```
import QtQuick 2.11         // <---
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 // <---

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    title: "MainWindow"
    width: 640
    height: 480

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        id: menuBar
        Menu {
            id: editMenu
            title: "&Edit"

            MenuItem {
                id: copyItem
                text: "Copy"
                shortcut: StandardKey.Copy
                onTriggered: console.log("copy")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now.

Comment: @rengel If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, that's the best way to thank, if you do not know how to do it please check the [tour]